# How do I conditionally add an incrementing number to a field?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server 2017; I have a table like this:

```
FlexID (int) | ColorCode (varchar) | MPID (varchar) | ...other fields
---------------------------------------------------------------------
12           | RD14                | 1234
<NULL>       | G21D                | <NULL>
<NULL>       | <NULL>              | <NULL>
14           | RD14                | 1235
12           | <NULL>              | <NULL>
```

FlexID and ColorCode are not unique, but MPID is unique if not null. I'd like to select out of this such that if both FlexID and ColorCode are not null then take the MPID, otherwise take a value `'UNDEFINED' + n` where n is some number that increments for each UNDEFINED case. I know I need something like this:

```
SELECT 
       CASE
           WHEN FLEXID is NULL
                OR ColorCode is NULL THEN 'UNDEFINED' --tack on an incrementing number starting at 1
           ELSE [MPID]
       END AS ID
FROM myTable
```

But I don't know how to get the behavior I want. Output should look like:

```
ID
--
1234
UNDEFINED1
UNDEFINED2
1235
UNDEFINED3
```

The idea here is to add on the `n`th number to make a unique value. I do need to start at `n=1` so using `ROWNUM` won't work for me. I know I'll have to have some ORDER BY part to this - it doesn't matter too much which column is used to ORDER BY.

Comment: @RaymondNijland - I'm not selecting FLEXID, I'm building a selection from the MPID column, but I don't take the MPID if FLEXID or ColorCode is null

Comment: Perhaps you should have an example where there is a value for `MPID` but not `FlexID` or `ColorCode` then? You don't actually show that scenario (and therefore I haven't catered for it).

Comment: Yes i geuss need some more coffee because now i see what going on, you just want to replace/generate MPID column value based on some filters.. One problem how should SQL Server know which record is 1, 2 or 3 without something that indentifies the order, SQL is orderless by default.

Comment: @Larnu - that's okay. Your answer got me were I needed to go. Instead of `ISNULL` I'm just using the  `... + CONVERT(...` in the `ELSE` part of my `CASE`. Business rules guarantee (or rather, are contracted to guarantee) that if FLEXID and ColorCode exist, there will be a MPID. If FLEXID or ColorCode are null, I don't care what value is in MPID; I will take `'UNDEFINDED' +n`

Comment: @RaymondNijland - a good call out - in my case, it doesn't matter which order SQL Server picks. It only matters that it starts at `n=1` and increments by +1 each time I get an `UNDEFINED`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *should* get you the result you want:

```
ISNULL(MPID, 'UNDEFINED' + CONVERT(varchar(5),ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MPID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))))
```

Note that the number that the Undefined row is effectively random; as it'll be in whatever order SQL Server processes the rows in (which may, or may not, be the same each time).

*Note: You haven't defined the length of the datatype for your column `MPID`. This is lower than a `varchar(10)` you'll have truncation issues (and if it's a `varchar(10)`, they'll begin at `'UNDEFINED10'`. If `MPID` has a low value for the length you'll need to convert it to an appropriate size in the above expression.*

Comment: This works for me, thank you! As I mentioned in the question comments, I used your answer in a `CASE` instead of the `ISNULL` to get the desired result. Thank you again... for some reason, I thought `ROW_NUMBER` would get me some n incremented by the number of rows between each UNDEFINED

Comment: That's what the `PARTITION BY` is sorting out, @ArcherBird. Each unique `MPID` is being given a unique set of row numbers. As a result, all the rows where `MPID` have a value of `NULL` are put into the same grouping.